# How refresh menu of NSPopupButton programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspopupbutton

This is a Core Data app made of several views, each contained in its own Xib. Across the app, I have several NSPopupButton displaying data from various Core Data entities, with bindings done the traditional way in interface builder and all works well.

Except for two popup buttons which I had to populate programmatically instead of bindings because the data needs some treatment before display on the popup. One relates to an entity where I needed to use @distinctUNionOfObjects. The other relates to an entity of decimal numbers which required to undergo a customized number formatting sothat they are displayed as percentages (with the percent sign).

In order to populate these 2 popups, I've generated the arrays of data in awakeFromNib for the related view. Here is the code:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"xib_name" bundle:nil];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    [self setTitle:@"view_title"];
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // fetch request on entity
    // data treatment and creation of an array with the result
    [popupButton addItemsWithTitles:array];
}
```

Fine, but when I add data to these entities feeding the popups (via tables or text fields on other views of the app), then come back to the views with the popups, the buttons are not updated with the new content. I understand, it's because the content is created in awakeFromNib, and showing again the related view does not re-awake the Nib. But then how can I made these popup buttons automatically updated when the source entity gets modified or receives new data? I see the changes only after restarting the app.

Or maybe I missed something and it is possible to do all that via bindings in interface builder, in the first place?

Thanks for advise.

=== Edit to specify that [controller rearrangeObjects] has no effect.